# action.PROCESS_TEXT activity not listed in EditText with Oreo

Tags: android

I'm using the `action_PROCESS_TEXT` intent to provide a custom text selection action.  On Marshmallow I am getting my action displayed on both readonly text and `EditText` controls and my code successfully displays/returns results.

On Oreo (Pixel 2 XL) my action is successfully displayed on read only text but I am not getting my action displayed on `EditText` controls, either in my own app or others.  I also notice that other process text app's such as Google Translate are only randomly displayed.

Google docs are very basic for this and I'm relying on the original [blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/custom-text-selection-actions-with-action-process-text-191f792d2999), has something changed?

Here's my relevant manifest and activity code

**Manifest**

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        ...
        <activity
            android:name=".TranslateActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Activity**

```
package mynamespace

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.ClipData
import android.content.ClipboardManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_translate.*

class TranslateActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var readOnly = true
    val translator = Translator()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_translate)
        setTitle(R.string.app_name)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener({
            onBackPressed()
        })

        translator.loadTranslations()

        handleIntent(intent)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)

        handleIntent(intent)
    }

    private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT_READONLY)) {
            readOnly = intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT_READONLY, false)
        }

        if (intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT)) {
            val text = intent.getCharSequenceExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT).toString()

            val result: String = translator.translate(text.toLowerCase())

            if (readOnly) {
                // Display result
                textViewTranslation.text = result
            } else {
                replaceText(result)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun replaceText(replacementText: String) {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT, replacementText)
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
        finish()
    }
...
}
```

Comment: That seems a bit like [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65822992).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, that does seem to be the same bug.  Irritating as this would be the primary entry point into my app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT` [does not work very well on Android 8.x](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65822992).

The good news is that this appears to be fixed in Android P. You won't have any problems in 2025 and onwards, once all the Android O devices get retired.